# Firebase verifyIdToken hangs

Tags: node.js, firebase, token

When I try to validate a token generated on the front end on my Node.js server, the function just hangs forever. Here is my code:

```
const firebase = require('firebase').initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: '******************.json',
  databaseURL: "https://**********************.firebaseio.com",
}, 'admin')

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  co(function*(){

    // Verify token. Returns decoded token
    const token = yield firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(req.cookies.firebase_token)

    res.render('index')
  })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err
    })
})
```

I am using Firebase 3.4.1 from npm and node -v 6.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I was sending the wrong data in the cookie. Use the `firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true)` function to get the correct token.

Comment: That shouldn't be the cause of hanging. It would return `Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token` in case of an invalid token